# Why my while loop causes infinite output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to build a small program that includes a while loop:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    while (x != '|' || y != '|') {
        cout << "Please enter two numbers: \n";
        cin >> x >> y;
        cout << "You entered: " << x << " and " << y << "\n\n" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and ran on both my windows box with visual studio and my linux box, and when the break requirement is filled my terminal/cmd fills up infinitely like an infinite loop. I've searched in quite a few places and couldn't find a clear answer. I have tried making the while infinite and putting the break parameter inside to no avail. I have a feeling it has to do with putting the vertical symbol in an integer, but I have had for loops running well with it. The lesson I'm in asks for it and I have workarounds that are 'okay', but would like to know a clean/standard way of doing this.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  If you are expecting to input `'|'`, you should not use an `int`. I t looks like you haven't decided whether your variables hold `char` or `int`.

Comment: The integer value of the `'|'` character, which is what you're comparing against, is not what you get when you give `cin >> x;` the string "|".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop is because you never check for input failure. After the line `cin >> x >> y` add:

```
if ( !cin )
    break;
```

Bear in mind that `x` and `y` are ints, so they can only store numbers. When you write `x != '|'` you are testing whether the person successfully entered the number matching the ASCII character code of `|`.  If you want to be able to inspect each character the person entered, input into a `string` instead.

Comment: This worked, but what exactly does this if statement do? I'm having trouble understanding the !cin part. I also figured that the code would be the same and the int would match breaking the statement.

Comment: Streams have error flags. When you convert a stream to `bool` (e.g. when doing `!` on it) it gives `false` if there is an error flag.  When extraction via `>>` fails,  an error flag is set.  So `if ( !cin ) break;` breaks if the extraction failed.

Comment: Ooh... Thanks! I see what's going on.